# XML to Json using Json-lib

Tags: java, android, xml, json

I'm trying to do a project in Android where I have a document  xml from a web  and i want to convert in Json.

I'm trying this:

```
    URL url;
    InputStream in;

    try {


    url = new URL("http://www.aemet.es/xml/municipios/localidad_41091.xml");
    in = url.openStream();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String result, line = reader.readLine();
    result = line;

    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
        result+=line;
    }

    XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer();  
    JSON json = serializer.read( result );

    System.out.println(json.toString());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but does not work ... can someone help me

Comment: you need to parse your xml and then you will able to create its representation in json

Answer (score 1):

Send the entire xml document as string instead of reading line by line

```
 import java.io.InputStream;

    import net.sf.json.JSON;
    import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer;

    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

    public class ConvertXMLtoJSON {

            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                    InputStream is = 
                            ConvertXMLtoJSON.class.getResourceAsStream("sample-xml.xml");
                    String xml = IOUtils.toString(is);

                    XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer(); 
                    JSON json = xmlSerializer.read( xml );  
                    System.out.println( json.toString(2) );
            }
    }
```

Comment: TThank you.

Now the problem is with xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer XMLSerializer ();

  does not recognize the class and  I've made sure that I download the libraries contain.

I tried both the last and with the 2.0