# How to listen to any Messaging queue & convert XML to XSD in Java?

Tags: java, json, xml, xsd, activemq-classic

i want to listen to a any queue & retrieve XML messages from that Queue. Say active MQ.

Once I receive , the XML , I want to convert it into secondary format.
Please tell me how ?
Sample XML i will receive in the queue looks like this :

```
<customer id="87866">
<age>55</age>
<name>Peter</name>
</customer>
```

Answer (score 1):

For JMS Listner:

Customer

```
package com.jms;


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    String name;
    int age;
    int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", id=" + id + "]";
    }

}
```

MyMessageListener

```
  package com.jms;
    import java.io.StringReader;
    import java.io.StringWriter;

    import javax.jms.Message;  
import javax.jms.MessageListener;  
import javax.jms.TextMessage;  
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;


public class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener{  
        @Override  
        public void onMessage(Message m) {  
            TextMessage message=(TextMessage)m;  
            try{  
                String xml = message.getText();

                //Get customer POJO
                Customer customer = generateEntity(xml);
                System.out.println(customer);

                //Convert POJO to json and update in mongodb
                convertEntityToJsonAndUpdateDB(customer);

            }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();  }  
        }  

   private static   Customer generateEntity(String xml){
       Customer customer = null;
       try{ 
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        customer = (Customer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
      }catch(Exception ex){
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    return customer;
   }


   private static void convertEntityToJsonAndUpdateDB(Customer customer){
    try{  
      StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.writeValue(writer, customer);
      System.out.println("Json:"+writer.toString());
      // To connect to mongodb server
      MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
      // connect to database
       DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test" );
         System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
         //Insert the json
         DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("mycollection");
         DBObject dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(writer.toString());
          collection.insert(dbObject);
         System.out.println("DB Insertion Successful"); 
     }catch(Exception ex){
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }

    }
}
```

TestListener

```
package com.jms;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;  

public class TestListener {  
 public static void main(String[] args) {  
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx=new GenericXmlApplicationContext();  
    ctx.load("classpath:applicationContext.xml");  
    ctx.refresh();  

    while(true){}  
 }  
}
```

mdb

```
package com.jms;

import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;


public class TestMongoDB {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     try{     
       // To connect to mongodb server
          MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
          // connect to database
           DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test" );
             System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
             //Insert the json
             DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("mycollection");
             //For querying mondo db
             DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
                while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(cursor.next());
                }
         }catch(Exception ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you're trying to solve two different problems here.

First, the conversion part:
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509777/xml-to-json-using-json-lib) shows a nice way to convert XML into JSON without any need to know the structure.

Another approach would be to use [JAXB](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) to unmarshal the XML into Java objects, which can then be serialized into JSON, for example by [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).  (This approach would be a bit more work, and is more brittle but would give you more control over the incoming format, and allow you to perform business logic and transformation in between, if required.

Second, listening to a JMS queue - this will depend on your library, but I've found ActiveMQ very easy to get going with.  A [quickstart guide](http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html) should give you detailed explanations of how to write a quick consumer.

Is this what you were looking for?  Need more/different detail?